# Java - class, get new array of objects

Tags: java, algorithm, class

I need some help with this exercise.

I want to print the salary of all the employees together, but I can't get it to work.

When I create a new department, I want to to receive work that I am writing only the name of the object(Worker), not re-enter information.

Actual Result (it goes wrong at the print of 0):

```
id: 1234567 name: david Hourly Wage: 25 Number Of Hours: 50 Final Salary: 1250
id: 234567 name: foo Hourly Wage: 50 Number Of Hours: 30 Final Salary: 1500
0
calculate Department Salery: 0
```

Expected result: Calculation of salaries of all workers together.

**Main Class**

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker work1 = new Worker("1234567");
        work1.name = "david";
        work1.Number_Of_Hours = 50;
        work1.Hourly_Wage = 25;

        Worker work2 = new Worker("234567","foo",50,30);

        work1.calculateSalery(55);
        work2.calculateSalery(60);

        System.out.println(work1.toString());
        System.out.println(work2.toString());


        Department cp = new Department();
        cp.addEmploy("123", "av", 25, 50);

        System.out.println(cp.calculateDepartmentSalery());

        System.out.println(cp.toString());
    }
}
```

**Class Worker**

```
public class Worker {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public int Hourly_Wage;
    public int Number_Of_Hours;

    public Worker(String _id) {
        id = _id;
    }

    public void addHoure(int hours) {
        Number_Of_Hours += hours;
    }

    public Worker(String _id, String _name, int _Hourly_Wage,
                  int _Number_Of_Hours) {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        Hourly_Wage = _Hourly_Wage;
        Number_Of_Hours = _Number_Of_Hours;
    }

    public void clearHour() {
        Number_Of_Hours = 0;
    }

    int FinalSalary = 0;

    public int calculateSalery(int h) {
        int cal = 0;
        if (h > Number_Of_Hours) {
            cal = h - Number_Of_Hours;
            cal = cal * ((Hourly_Wage / 100) * 120);
            FinalSalary = (Hourly_Wage * Number_Of_Hours) + cal;
        }

        else {
            FinalSalary = Hourly_Wage * Number_Of_Hours;
        }
        return FinalSalary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "id: " + id + " name: " + name + " Hourly Wage: "
                + Hourly_Wage + " Number Of Hours: " + Number_Of_Hours
                + " Final Salary: " + FinalSalary;
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Class Department**

```
public class Department {
    public String name;
    public int Annual_budget;
    public final int Max_Workers = 30;
    private Worker[] arrWork = null;
    private int Index;

    public Department() {
        arrWork = new Worker[Max_Workers];
        Index = 0;
    }

    public boolean addEmploy(String _id, String _name, int _Hourly_Wage,
                             int _Number_Of_Hours) {
        arrWork[Index] = new Worker(_id, _name, _Hourly_Wage, _Number_Of_Hours);
        return true;
    }

    int result = 0;

    public int calculateDepartmentSalery() {

        for (int i = 0; i < Index; i++) {
            if (arrWork[i] != null)
                result += arrWork[i].FinalSalary;
        }
        return result;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "calculate Department Salery: " + result;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: please include inside the question what is going wrong, what is the actual result, and what is the expected result.

Comment: Ok changed, thank you.

Comment: Your naming is bad: Class names should start with Uppercase letter, and methods and fields should start with lowercase letter. However, you problem is that `Index` is not incremented by `addEmploy`, so it's still `0` when `calculateDepartmentSalery()` is called, and loop will do nothing. Also, you should not store the result in a field. What happens if `calculateDepartmentSalery()` is called twice? Oops. Learn to debug, and you'll be able to find errors like this way faster than write a question here and waiting for answers.

Comment: I'm not going to exercise just cause you need help!

Comment: @scndjs Well, you could find out yourself using a debugger. Hint: if index is 0, and loop runs from 0 to some value smaller than index, how many times will the loop run?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to review basic `OOP`, [object-oriented programming](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html). Variables defined in `Worker` and `Department` should be private, using methods such as `getID()` and `setID(String ID)`. The workers should be stored in an `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
workers.add(new Worker(*input proper data*));
```

If you plan to sum the workers' salaries, you may loop through `workers` by using a `for-each` loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for(Worker w : workers){
sum += w.calculateSalary(w.getH());//you may need to include an "h" variable in the worker class
}
```

Also, these calls:

```
work1.calculateSalery(55);
work2.calculateSalery(60);
```

Are absolutely pointless since you're not storing these calculations anywhere. Since `calculateSalery();` returns type `int` you may store these values in an `int` variable. However, you may want to use `double` variable types for things such as `Hourly_Wage, Number_Of_Hours,` and the method `calculateSalery();`